# Characterising exact sequence in terms of (quasi-)identities

Tags: ct.category-theory, diagram-chase

First of all, hello everyone and thanks in advance of any kind of help.

I am currently working on automated proofs of diagram chases. To this end, I have to characterise the property of $A \overset{f}{\to}B \overset{g}{\to} C$ being an exact sequence, where $f,g$ are morphisms between $R$-modules, in terms of algebraic (quasi-)identities. So, I am trying to find identities or implications of identities involving $f$, $g$ (and possible other, auxiliary morphisms) that characterise $\text{im}(f) = \ker(g)$.

Characterising the inclusion $\text{im}(f) \subseteq \ker(g)$ is pretty straight forward. This simply translates into $gf = 0$. But so far, I could not characterise the other inclusion $\ker(g) \subseteq \text{im}(f)$ in terms of algebraic (quasi-)identities.

Maybe someone can help me out here.

Comment: I am not an expert, so I do not know if this observation helps in any way but, after you know that $Im(f)\subseteq Ker(g)$, you can say that $g$ induces a unique map $\bar g\colon B/Im(f)\to C$. Then, the equality $Ker(g)=Im(f)$ is equivalent to $Ker(\bar g)=0$, that is, "$\bar g(x)=0$ implies x=0" for all $x\in  B/Im(f)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Very interesting observation. The only problem here is that I cannot really work with information about single elements - meaning I cannnot incorporate identities such as $x = 0$. I can only work with something like $\bar{g} = 0$.

Comment: Again, I do not know if this helps, but note that elements "are" very particular maps. Let me explain, for an $R$-module $M$, an element $x\in M$ is the same as a homomorphism $R\rightarrow M$ (uniquely determined by $1\mapsto x$). Then, in the setting of my previous comment, the last part of the sentence can be reformulated by saying that "$\bar g\circ \varphi =0$ implies $\varphi=0$, for all $\varphi\colon R\to B/Im(f)$"

Comment: Oohh yes of course. Right. I think this might really help. Thanks a lot!